# How to perform model validation in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-activerecord

I have a rails application where **Activity** is one of the resources with the following attributes:

- status (recording the status of activity "in progress", "complete")
- start  (date when activity started)
- end    (date when activity ended)

I want to create a new record for activity with status "in progress", given there is no existing activity with the same status. I believe this can be done using model validation, but being new to rails I have no idea how.

Comment: Are you using `enum` for `status` attribute?

Comment: I am using `string` at the moment but `enum` would make more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `status` is a `enum` you may do:

```
class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: [ :in_progress, :complete ]

  validates_uniqueness_of :status, if: :in_progress?
end
```

This validation restricts you have only one `activity` with `in_progress` status.

Also if `status` is a string you may do:

```
class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :status, if: proc { |activity| activity.status == 'in_progress' }
end
```